# Subsetting dataset when data contains no clear groups to subset

Tags: r

Hi Stackoverflow community,

**Background:**
I'm using a population modelling program to try to predict genetic outcomes of threatened species populations given a range of management scenarios. At the end of each of my population modelling scenarios I have a .csv file containing information on all the final living individuals over all 1,000 iterations of the modeled population which includes information on all surviving individual's genotypes.

**What I want:**
From this .csv output file I'd like to determine the frequency of the allele `"6"` in the columns `"Allele2a"` and `"Allele2b"` in each of the 1,000 iterations of the model contained in the file.

**The Problem:**
The .csv file I'm trying to determine the allele 6's frequency from does not contain information that can be used to easily subset the data (from what  can see) into the separate iterations. I have no idea how to split this dataset into it's respective iterations given that the number of individuals surviving to the end of the model (and subsequently the number of individual rows in each iteration) is not the same, and there is no clear subsettable points.

Any guidance on how to separate this data into iteration units which can be analysed, or how to determine the frequency of the allele without complex subsetting would be very greatly appreciated. If any further information is required please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks!

EDIT: When input into R the data looks like this:

```
            Living<-read.csv("Living Ind.csv", header=F)
            colnames(Living) <- c("Iteration","ID","Pop","Sex","alive","Age","DamID","SireID","F","FInd","MtDNA","Alle1a","Alle1b","Alle2a","Alle2b")
            attach(Living)

            Living
                      Iteration   ID Pop Sex alive Age DamID SireID     F  FInd MtDNA Alle1a Alle1b Alle2a Alle2b
1     Iteration    1  NA        NA  NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2                 NA  NA        NA  NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
3               2511   2   M  TRUE  19   545   1376 0.000 0.000   545   1089   2751      6      6
4               2515   2   F  TRUE  18   590   1783 0.000 0.000   590   1180   3566      5      5
5               2519   2   F  TRUE  18   717   1681 0.000 0.000   717   1434   3362      4      6
6               2526   2   M  TRUE  17   412   1780 0.000 0.000   412    823   3559      4      6
7               2529   2   F  TRUE  17   324   1473 0.000 0.000   324    647   2945      5      6
107             2676   2   F  TRUE   1  2576   2526 0.000 0.000   621   3876   3559      6      4
108               NA  NA        NA  NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
109   Iteration    2  NA        NA  NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
110               NA  NA        NA  NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
111             2560   2   M  TRUE  18   703   1799 0.000 0.000   703   1406   3598      6      6
112             2564   2   M  TRUE  18   420   1778 0.000 0.000   420    840   3555      4      6
113             2578   2   F  TRUE  17   347   1778 0.000 0.000   347    693   3555      3      5
114             2581   2   M  TRUE  16   330   1454 0.000 0.000   330    659   2907      6      6
115             2584   2   F  TRUE  16   568   1593 0.000 0.000   568   1135   3185      6      5
116             2591   2   F  TRUE  13   318   1423 0.000 0.000   318    635   2846      3      6
117             2593   2   M  TRUE  13   341   1454 0.000 0.000   341    682   2907      6      6
118             2610   2   M  TRUE   8  2578   2582 0.000 0.000   347    693   2908      5      6
119             2612   2   M  TRUE   8  2578   2582 0.000 0.000   347   3555    660      3      6
```

Just a total mess I'm afraid.

Here's a link to a copy of the .csv file. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl6ncy5i0152uv1/Living%20Ind.csv?dl=0

Comment: Could you show the desired output for the input data you've shown?

Comment: You'll have to forgive my poor R terminology knowledge, but I think I'd like to convert this input into an output containing a separate array (or matrix, I'm unsure) for each iteration group, which can then have the presence of the allele "6" in columns A2a and A2b determined in each iteration array/matrix. Alternatively, there may be a better way to get the information I desire (presence of allele "6" in each iteration) out of this dataset, but I am unsure of how to do so without somehow splitting the data by iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing your data. It makes this *much* easier. In future you should always do this with questions on SO.

The basic issue is transforming your original data into something more easy to manipulate in R. Since your data-set is fairly large, I'm using the `data.table` package, but you could also do basically the same thing using data.frames in base R.

```
library(data.table)
url <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl6ncy5i0152uv1/Living%20Ind.csv?dl=1"
DT  <- fread(url,header=FALSE, showProgress = FALSE)          # import data
DT  <- DT[!is.na(V2)]                                         # remove blank lines (rows)

brks <- which(DT$V1=="Iteration")                             # identify iteration header rows
iter <- DT[brks,]$V2                                          # extract iteration numbers
DT   <- DT[-brks,Iter:=rep(iter,diff(c(brks,nrow(DT)+1))-1)]  # assign iteration number to each row
DT   <- DT[-brks]                                             # remove iteration header rows
DT[,V1:=NULL]                                                 # remove first column
setnames(DT, c("ID","Pop","Sex","alive","Age","DamID","SireID","F","FInd","MtDNA","Alle1a","Alle1b","Alle2a","Alle2b","Iteration"))

# now can count fraction of allele 6 easily.
DT[,list(frac=sum(Alle2a==6 | Alle2b==6)/.N), by=Iteration]
#       Iteration      frac
#    1:         1 0.7619048
#    2:         2 0.9130435
#    3:         3 0.6091954
#    4:         4 0.8620690
#    5:         5 0.8850575
#   ---
```

If you are going to be analyzing large datasets like this a lot, it would probably be worth your while to learn how to use `data.table`.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I'm afraid that my data isn't quite as clean as I made it in the original example and I can't seem to get it to work. I've edited the original to include the mess of an input I'm trying to work with; iterations are much more squished together. Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: Can you upload `Living Ind.csv` somewhere and post a link. Trying to guess the format isn't working out.

Comment: I've added a download link for the .csv file in the main question.

Comment: OK. Changed my answer to accommodate your actual data set.

Comment: Originally I was trying to make my dataset problem interpretable, but I see now that I just ended up completely misrepresenting the issue - I'll add the original data only in the future. This solution works beautifully, thank you so much for your help. I will most certainly be reading the `data.table` vignette for future reference.

Comment: No worries. Since you're new to SO, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).